# Definition-era comments cannot be viewed for proposals now in Commitment

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, area-51, commitment-phase

Yes, it's very early into the new phase to report bugs, but technically this is a bug in the definition phase!

Once a question is moved to the Commitment Phase, you can't expand the hidden comments shown at the old Definition Phase link. For example, [the Gaming proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1338?phase=definition) has 30 comments past what is shown, which is greater than how many I saw before. But if I click "show 30 more comments", nothing happens!

This is also the case for hidden comments on the example questions, and I tested Apocalypse Defense as well. However, for [Food and Cooking](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1288/food-and-cooking), which is still in the definition phase, the expansion works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for catching this -- we had clearly disabled a bit too much of the definition-phase UI for proposals in commitment. It's been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed. Fix in progress as we speak.