# show <N> more comments doesn't work in Commitment phase

Tags: bug, area-51, commitment-phase

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Definition-era comments cannot be viewed for proposals now in Commitment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53593/definition-era-comments-cannot-be-viewed-for-proposals-now-in-commitment)

High-ranked comments on questions in the commitment phase are shown, but the  "show  more comments" link doesn't work, and thus you can't see the other comments.

Comment: @Dr. Gonzo, yep, I think we must have reported that at about the same time

Comment: Yep, it looked like you guys were two seconds apart.